# How can I understand "PieChart.Data"?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I need help with understand specific class used in code:

```
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

How can I understand `PieChart.Data`? Why a class has this type, why not is `Data`?

Thanks!

Comment: Because `Data` is a [nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) inside class `PieChart`.

Comment: Note you can use an import: `import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.Data` that allows you to write `ObservableList<Data>`.

Answer (score 0):

*why not is `Data`* : Because you have different type of Data for different types of Chart :

- [`PieChart.Data`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/PieChart.Data.html) for PieChart **:** `name + value`
- [`XYChart.Data<X,Y>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html) for LineChart, AreaChart, ...  **:** `xValue + yValue ( + extraValue)`

It allow to distinguish

---

More info on [`JavaFX Chart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/charts.htm)